# "Error browser operation: An error occurred trying to start process 'C:\home\chrome-win\Win64-1108766\chrome-win\chrome.exe'

Tags: .net, azure-functions, puppeteer, html-to-pdf

` public async Task GeneratePdfReportAsync(string pdfData, string fileName, ILogger logger)
{

```
 try
 {

     logger.LogInformation("Started PDF generation.");

     //"C:\\Users\\naveen\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\chrome-win" -- temp path folder in local
     // Create a temporary directory to store Chromium
     string chromiumDownloadPath = Path.Combine(@"C:\home", "chrome-win");
     Directory.CreateDirectory(chromiumDownloadPath);
     logger.LogInformation("Step 2.");
     // Create a BrowserFetcher to download Chromium
     var browserFetcher = new BrowserFetcher(new BrowserFetcherOptions
     {
         Path = chromiumDownloadPath
     });
     logger.LogInformation("Step 3.");
     // Download Chromium
     await browserFetcher.DownloadAsync(BrowserFetcher.DefaultChromiumRevision);

     logger.LogInformation("Step 4.");

     // Launch Puppeteer using the downloaded Chromium executable
     var browser = await Puppeteer.LaunchAsync(new LaunchOptions
     {
         Headless = true,
         ExecutablePath = Path.Combine(chromiumDownloadPath, "Win64-1108766", "chrome-win", "chrome.exe")

     });

     var page = await browser.NewPageAsync();

     string responseMessage = await page.GetContentAsync();
     logger.LogInformation("New page created successfully.");

     string encodedPdfData = WebUtility.UrlEncode(pdfData);

     string url = $"https://htmltopdftemplates.blob.core.windows.net/htmltopdftemplates/report.html?data={pdfData}";
     logger.LogInformation($"Navigating to URL: {url}");

     await page.GoToAsync(url);
     logger.LogInformation("Page navigation successful.");
     await page.EmulateMediaTypeAsync(MediaType.Screen);
     logger.LogInformation("Media type emulation successful.");

     // Generate PDF
     var pdfOptions = new PdfOptions { Format = PaperFormat.A4 };
     var pdfStream = await page.PdfStreamAsync(pdfOptions);
     logger.LogInformation("PDF Stream generated successfully.");


     // Upload PDF to Azure Blob Storage
   
     await browser.CloseAsync();
     logger.LogInformation("Browser closed successfully.");
 }
 catch (Exception ex)
 {
     logger.LogError($"Error during browser operation: {ex.Message}");
     throw;
 }
```

}

after steo 4 logs . am getting issue after this line. i need to run my chrome.exe in my azure env .currently am not able to run . i have tried all silutions with using old packages of pupeeter too still issue not fiuxed